# How to clone complete repo in YAML pipeline instead of sparse checkout?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, vfs

Azure devops VFS pipeline is doing sparse checkout instead of full clone on repo.?is there anyway we can do a complete repo clone?

Comment: Why do you need it?

Comment: We have few playbooks in same repo and TASK would be running a set of ansible playbooks on AKS cluster created from previous task in YAML pipeline

Comment: So, you need to be sure, that you do not have any artifacts from the previous run?

Comment: yes, it only has files from other directory where master YAML is present, since it is doing sparse check out on files instead of repo cloning which is an input to YAML pipeline, for proceeding to next step i need to switch to a different directory on local workspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tune your checkout process and achieve similar results using a different way.
First of all, you can clean the repo during the checkout process:

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  clean: true
```

Next, you can check out more than one repo:

```
steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: MyGitHubToolsRepo
- checkout: git://MyResourcesProject/resources
```

Moreover, you can place every into the different folder using "path" parameter (path will be relative to the agent's build directory).

```
steps:
- checkout: self
  path: PutMyCodeHere
```

You can find other configuration properties [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#checkout).